Can interlinear gloss shows only specific metalinguistic elements?
Background
For my research I need to create interlinear linguistic gloss between Russian and Indonesian. Russian is characterized with a highly inflective morphosyntactic grammar, and as such glossing Russian sentences into other languages will result in a gloss loaded with metalinguistic information.
For the purpose of simplifying my question, let's say that I only have three sentences of which I need to gloss. From 3 of the sentences, I do not necessarily need to show all of the metalinguistic elements from 1 sentence. I just need to show a specific metalinguistic element from that one sentence. For example, I just need to mark the words governed by the genitive case GEN.
To give an example, I will generate a LaTeX document and its typeset to demonstrate the data that I am working with.

Generating LaTeX gb4e gloss
Here is the interlinear linguistic glosses, made using the gb4e package. The tex document is reproducible in the code sample section below. In this section, I will show the result of the gloss only (the typeset):

As seen through the gloss, the third sentence did not show the complete metalinguistic information of the Russian words, I just decide to chose specific metalinguistic element from the sentence indicated by the LEX abbreviation, as well as PAR because Indonesian lacks the equivalent translation for that exact particle/interjection.
The reason for such "cherrypicking" of the metalinguistic element is because I am also working the Critical Discourse Analysis (CDA) framework, and I needed to focus whether the sentence employs the relevant CDA strategies that I am working on. Therefore in the third gloss I only show LEX in the metalinguistic gloss, to indicate that the sentence employs the CDA strategy (and of course the PAR to compensate the lack of equivalent translation of such particles).
I also could not currently find any detailed guidelines for glossing (or anything related thereof), except for the Leipzig glossing rule, but it unfortunately contains no relevant information to my question.

Question
Is it the norm to create interlinear gloss with complete metalinguistic element of the sentence? Would it be accepted by the consensus to only show specific metalinguistic elements for one or two of the glosses? To my defense it would make it easier for the readers to process the gloss information if I focus only on a metalinguistic element.

Code sample
This is the code I used in LaTeX with gb4e to create interlinear linguistic gloss.
%okegas yuk bisa yuk

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{times}

\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=3cm,
 right=3cm,
 top=3cm,
 bottom=3cm
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}


\begin{document}

 \begin{exe}
 
 \let\eachwordone=\it
 
 \noautomath
\setlength{\glossglue}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

 \ex %Glosa 1
 {\bf (Glosa 1)}
 \glll \?{В} \?{результате} \?{рейдов} \?{по} \?{поиску} \?{геев} \?{в} \?{Чечне} \\
v rezul'tat-e rejd-ov po poisk-u ge-ev v čečn-e \\
pada hasil\textsc{-prep} serangan\textsc{-jam.gen} melalui pencarian\textsc{-dat} gay\textsc{-jam.gen} di Chechnya\textsc{-prep} \\
 \trans “Akibat operasi pencarian kelompok gay di Chechnya” \\

 \ex %Glosa 2
{\bf (Glosa 2)}
\glll \?{Ранее} \?{штрафы} \?{за} \?{гей-пропаганду} \?{выписывались} \?{только} \?{на} \?{основании} \?{местных} \?{законов} \\
ranee štraf-y za {gej.propagand-u} vypi-syva-l-i-s' tol'ko na osnovani-i mestn-yx zakon-ov \\
dulu hukum\textsc{-jam} mengenai {propaganda.gay\textsc{-aku}} diberlakukan\textsc{-perf-lamp-jam-refl} hanya pada basis\textsc{-prep} setempat\textsc{-adj.jam.gen} hukum\textsc{-n.jam.gen} \\
\trans “Dulu, denda untuk propaganda gay hanya diberlakukan berdasarkan hukum daerah” \\

\ex %Glosa 3
{\bf (Glosa 3)} % strategi
\glll \?{Российские} \?{гомосексуалисты} \?{пользуются} \?{всеми} \?{теми} \?{же} \?{правами}, \?{что} \?{и} \?{остальные} \?{граждане}, \?{занимают} \?{различные} \?{посты}, \?{делают} \?{карьеру} \\ % teks rusia
rossijskie gomoseksualisty pol'zujutsjya vsemi temi že pravami, čto i ostal'nye graždane, zanimajut različnye posty, delajut kar'eru \\ % transliterasi latin
rusia homoseksual menikmati\textsc{.lks} semua itu \textsc{par} hak, yang dan lainnya warga, memegang berbagai jabatan, memiliki karir \\ % glosa metalinguistik
\trans “Kelompok gay Rusia menikmati hak yang dengan warga negara lainnya, memiliki berbagai jabatan, dan memiliki karir” \\ % terjemahan bebas

\end{exe}

\end{document}


The verb выписывались is analyzed and glossed not quite correctly, this verb is imperfective. A better way of breaking it into morphemes is vypis-yva-l-i-s’ and glossing is diberlakukan-IMPERF-LAMP-JAM-REFL, where I used IMPERF for “imperfective”.

Thanks for the correction! @YellowSky
